# How to create Create Multiple Topics and Multiple Subscriptions in Azure Service Bus using terraform..?

Tags: azure, terraform, azureservicebus, terraform-provider-azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to create Azure service bus resource via terraform. I need to create multiple topics with the list of subscriptions.

For example:

Service bus have multiple topics (TOPIC1, TOPIC2...)  and each topics contains list of subscriptions (topic_1_sub, topic_2_sub...) whereas each subscription itself is an array

Topics = ["TOPIC1", "TOPIC2", "TOPIC3", "TOPIC4"]

Subscriptions = [topic_1_sub, topic_2_sub, topic_3_sub]

Value of subscriptions

topic_1_sub = ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4"]

topic_2_sub = ["sub5", "sub6", "sub7", "sub8"]

topic_3_sub = ["sub9", "sub10", "sub11", "sub12"]

Connectivity is showing in image:
[image: link topics with subscription]

Expected Output:

Service bus must contains all topics ( i.e. TOPIC1, TOPIC2 …)  and each topic must contains the subscriptions (i.e. TOPIC1 should be only contains subscription like topic_1_sub , TOPIC2 should be only contains subscription like topic_2_sub   and so on)

Comment: Can you provide TF code that you tried and any errors you get?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for the letting us know and sorry for the delay.
I am providing GitHub link. so it is easy to refer. please take a look and get back to me if any. code path : 
[servicebus](https://github.com/sai2202/Krishna/blob/main/servicebus.tf)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping in for\_each nested resources with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600382/looping-in-for-each-nested-resources-with-terraform)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AyashkantBarik . while using that code also i am getting error:

local.servicebus is object with 3 attributes
Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".